# Does SQL Server automatically run ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [table] START FULL POPULATION on its own?

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-indexing, fulltext-index

Is there any process in SQL Server 2012 which will run a FULL POPULATION on its own?  We are having performance issues, and all fulltext indices are set for AUTO UPDATE_CRAWL.  But in looking at running threads from this query...

SELECT getdate() as "RunTime", st.text, qp.query_plan, a.* FROM sys.dm_exec_requests a CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(a.sql_handle) as st CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(a.plan_handle) as qp 
where session_id in(221)

...I found that this was one of the processes running...

ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[my_tbl_name] START FULL POPULATION

From what I have read, this should only be running if someone manually started it.  But there is nothing in our code to call that command.  Is there some process which triggers it automatically?  I wondered if we deleted all rows from the table and repopulated them then perhaps it would run, but I don't see anywhere in our code that this could be happening either.

We are CPU bound since migrating only 1/2 of our DB's from SQL 2005 to SQL 2012 and we are grasping at straws.  This is also on a VMware host, 1 CPU, 8 cores and 128 GB RAM.  Doesn't make sense.  Any advice appreciated.